# Qualitative graph for a function of $x^{3}$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I have this function:
$$f(x)=\frac{x(x^2-3)}{x^3-3x-3}$$
I need to draw its graph. I've tried with a classic study of a function but it cames out a mess. Any idea to simplify the study for draw the graph? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, sorry I wasn't on this platform in the last two days, I have done it now. Thank you.. :).

Comment: You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that

$$f(x)=\frac{x(x^2-3)}{x^3-3x-3}=f(x)=\frac{x^3-3x}{x^3-3x-3}=f(x)=1+\frac{3}{x^3-3x-3}$$

For a first sketch

- determine domain
- find the value for some "special" and/or "simple" point as x=0,1,etc.
- find the value for which denominator = 0 (and thus vertical asymptothes)
- find limit at $\pm \infty$

Then for a complete study we need use derivatives.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your reply. I tried to put the denominator equal to $0$ to find the domain (I tried to scompose it with Ruffini Theorem with no results) but it seems has complex coniugated solutions. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3-3x-3%3D0

Comment: For that you can consider the function $g(x)=x^3-3x-3$ and make a quick study for it in order to have  an idea about its roots. Note that g'(x)=3x^2-3=0 leads to $x=\pm 1$, and $g''(x)=6x$.

Comment: Tried to study $g(x)$ (it's domain in this case is $\mathbb{R}$, but when its a denominator it must be different from $0$) and I don't know how to managed complex coniugated solutions on $\mathbb{R}$. Moreover it's easy, as you've said, computing $g'(x)$ and $g''(x)$ for monothonicity and convexity but I can't define a domain for $f(x)$. Thank you.

Comment: @muserock92 for g(x) we can observe that for $x\to +\infty \implies g(x)\to +\infty$  and for $x\to -\infty \implies g(x)\to -\infty$ thus at least one root exists. Then it easy to verify that $x=-1$ correspond to a negative local maximum and x=1 to a negative local minimum then g(x) has only one root for $x>1$.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get a graph of $$f(x)=\frac{x(x^2-3)}{x^3-3x-3}$$

We look at intercepts, asymptotes and a few more points.

$f(x)=0$ gives you your $x$-intercepts.

$$f(x)=0 \implies x(x^2-3)=0 \implies x=0,\pm \sqrt 3$$
$$ x^3-3x-3=0 $$ gives you vertical asymptotes 
$$ x^3-3x-3=0\implies x=2.1038$$

which is the only vertical asymptote.

$$ \lim _{x\to \pm \infty }f(x) = 1$$

That is $y=1$ is a horizontal asymptote.

We use the above information to sketch a graph.

Then we verify our graph with a graphing utility.

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering how to solve $x^{3}-3x-3=0$. Tried with Ruffini theorem with no results. Thank you.

Comment: I used TI-84. Calculus to find the zeros of $x^{3}-3x-3=0$

Comment: Thank you, I have to learn to find the solutions without using a calculator.

Comment: Good luck. Numerical methods are the only way to solve some equations.